# ¿Se puede hacer un count() selectivo?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark

Tengo una pregunta con relación al `count()` en PySpark. Me gustaría saber si el `count()` permite hacer un conteo de registros de forma selectiva. Por ejemplo: quiero contar dentro de un campo del `df` los 0 que hay.

¿Hay alguna manera que no implique hacer `df.where(col("columna") == "0").count()`?

He intentado las combinaciones de `df.count("columna")` o `df.count(["columna])`

¿Se os ocurre alguna manera?

¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué dice la documentación al respecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

validando la pregunta que formulas podrías realizarlo a través de una agrupación si es lo que requieres (contará todos los posibles valores de la columna), algo similar a esto:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
dfAgrupado = dataFrame.groupBy(F.col("TuColumna")).count()
```

Si solo quieres ver un valor en específico podrías filtrarlo posteriormente:

```
dfAgrupado = dfAgrupado.filter(F.col("TuColumna") == 0)
```

Espero te sirva.